# How do I find a solution to the following equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ring-theory, divisibility, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to find a function $a$ of $x$ such that:
$a(x) \equiv 2x+1\bmod x^2+1$ and $a(x) \equiv 3\bmod x+1$.

Furthermore, $a(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ is an element of the stated quotient ring.

How do I find $a(x)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying the Chinese remainder theorem to the ring of polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980149/applying-the-chinese-remainder-theorem-to-the-ring-of-polynomials)